# How to use Google Maps APIs for indoor mapping in hybrid mobile app?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am using Ionic Framework and Cordova for Hybrid mobile application Development. How to use Google Maps APIs for indoor mapping in hybrid mobile app?

Here is the Link for Indoor Mapping from Google. [API Link for Indoor Mapping from Google](https://www.google.com/intl/en_uk/maps/about/partners/indoormaps/)

Comment: did you find any solution?